# SQL UPDATE tables whose name is passed by an array

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, variables

Imagine we've got a database with multiple tables. Example: table1, table2, table3.

```
Stucture of table1, table2, table3

+-----+---------+
|  id |  name   |
+-----+---------+
|  1  |  Jack   |
+-----+---------+
```

If we want to update one or two of them, with a simply:

```
UPDATE table1, table2 SET table1.name='Paul', table2.name='Alex'
```

But what if we don't directly know the name of these tables neither its new values. How could be do this if we got this data on an array which could be something like:

```
$array([0]=>(table1, Paul) [1]=>(table2, Alex))
```

How could be do it?

Comment: do you know what is loop?

Comment: You would need to dynamically build SQL strings. But the bigger issue is that you have 3 tables with the exact same structure. Instead, you should have _one_ table with a column that identifies the type or source and contains all of these rows together.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski maybe it is some kind of denormalization for better performance :)

Comment: Just extract the content of the array using loops and place that variable in place of table name